# Puppeteer freezes entire computer when browsing to multiple pages in rapid succession

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am making an app with puppeteer that, given a list of UPC codes, scrapes a website for images. However, my code freezes my computer when I run it. I am processing about 700 codes, so I expect my code to take a while, but I don't expect my computer to freeze. The only output is

```
(node:5837) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:5837) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:5837) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:5837) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

My code is

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import parse from 'csv-parse';
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

const parseCsv = async (filename: string): Promise<parse.Parser> => {
    let contents: Buffer = await fs.readFile(filename);
    const parser = parse(contents);

    return parser;
}

const processRow = async (row) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://www.example.com/search/?q=${row[5]}`);

    await browser.close();
}

(async () => {
    console.log('Reading file');
    const parser = await parseCsv(process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]);

    let i = 0;

    let results = []

    console.log('Extracting data');
    for await (let row of parser) {
        if (/\d/.test(row[5])) {
            results.push(row);
        }
    }

    console.log('Scraping');
    results.map(processRow);
})();
```

I have 16 GB of RAM, and am on POP! OS 20.10, if this helps.

Comment: Try to take `const browser = await puppeteer.launch();` out of `processRow`. I.e. launch just one single browser and use various pages.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty That didn't work, it still freezes my computer.

Comment: Then maybe do not open 700 pages in parallel, scrape consecutively or in small groups.

Comment: how can i do that? my client needs all 700 pages scraped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `results.map(processRow);` opens 700 pages in parallel. Try to process these pages sequentially. It will be slower, but safer:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import parse from 'csv-parse';
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const parseCsv = async (filename: string): Promise<parse.Parser> => {
        let contents: Buffer = await fs.readFile(filename);
        const parser = parse(contents);

        return parser;
    }

    console.log('Reading file');
    const parser = await parseCsv(process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]);

    let i = 0;

    let results = []

    console.log('Extracting data');
    for await (let row of parser) {
        if (/\d/.test(row[5])) {
            results.push(row);
        }
    }

    console.log('Scraping');
    for (const row of results) {
      await page.goto(`https://www.example.com/search/?q=${row[5]}`);
      //process the page
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

If you need both speed and safety, try to use [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster).